# Unable to access container $root in account myblobcontainer using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I'm trying to connect to an Azure blob file within a DataBricks notebook.

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.sas.myblobcontainer.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net",
  "mysastoken")

df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("inferSchema", "true").load(file_location)
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to access container $root in account badrulsblobcontainer using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them  in the configuration.
```

I have created a SAS key in Azure for my Container

Answer (score 3):

According to your error message, I think your SAS token does not work. I suggest you use create SAS token with [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Besides, regarding how to connect Azure blob, please refer to the [document](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html).

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.sas.<your-container-name>.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<the query string you copy>") 

dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
```

The result :
[image]

Comment: If you’re a Microsoft partner, I recommend you visiting aka.ms/devchat for personalized support on Azure. It’s free and 24x5.

Comment: After searching for 2 hours this is what solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @kiae   Since it is OK  for you, could you please accept it? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Comment: it's not my question so I don't think I can

Answer (score 0):

According to the information of your error, you have no access to get container data. In fact, if you configure a container with the permission(anonymous read access for blobs only), you only can read the blob within the container by anonymous request, but container data is not available. for more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources#grant-anonymous-users-permissions-to-containers-and-blobs).

Besides,  I find a good channel to solve azure queries: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3174960/dev-chat-for-office365-azure , all azure or O365 queris seems always will be able to be answered, you can have a try.